# Oracle - REPCAT$ Tables

Tags: oracle

I accidently dropped the REPCAT$_USER_PARM_VALUES table from the system schema in my oracle db. Will it cause any problems in the future? What are these repcat$ tables for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These tables are related to [**Oracle Advanced Replication**](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14226/toc.htm).

Although it is not advisable to drop them, you might just be fine if you are not using any Advanced Replication features.

Related :  [**DBMS_REPCAT**](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10733/rarrcatp.htm) package

Answer (score 2):

> I accidently dropped the REPCAT$_USER_PARM_VALUES table from the
>   system schema in my oracle db. Will it cause any problems in the
>   future?

Unless you take steps to make sure this kind of thing doesn't happen again, you will certainly have "problems in the future". I suggest you:

1. Tell your boss what has happened.
2. If you are sure that is the only table that has been dropped, consider recreating it - do a dummy install on another box of the ***exact*** same version of Oracle and get the DDL from there. Even if you don't use Advanced Replication, you have no guarantee that there isn't some dependency chain that means something else isn't broken.
3. Don't do any DDL as `sys`. Ever.
4. Don't even log in as `sys` or `system` unless you are doing something that *requires* you to do so.
5. Preferably leave the `system` and `sysaux` tablespaces alone - create your database objects in their own tablespaces or the default `users` tablespace.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Though I was using test database, I'll be careful not to touch these and sorry for the late reply.